# Adding readonly wysiwyg field to entity form

Tags: entities

I'm using entity forms and I want to add a wysiwyg text block in between two form fields, that is just an explanation text. This text does not need to be submitted and should not be editable for the user. It is just an explanation text block that needs to be in the form and that has to be entered via an wysiwyg editor in the backend as it contains some formatted stuff like an headline etc.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Markup module](https://www.drupal.org/project/markup).  Should do exactly what you're after.

> This module adds the ability for site admins to add "Markup" widgets
>   to the form. These essentially let designers of cck content-types
>   insert additional markup into the node/edit form to display to
>   content-authors. This is the equivalent of adding additional elements
>   to $form of the type '#markup'.